# make zsh prompt update each time a command is executed

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

## TLDR;

I need a way for `.zshrc` to automatically be sourced each time a command is executed. `PROMPT` needs to be updated each time a command is executed in order to show relevant information in the prompt.

## Reason

I use [Watson cli](https://github.com/TailorDev/Watson) for tracking time. On my previous bash setup, I prepended my prompt (`$PS1`) with a symbol that indicates whether the timer is running or not (red/green). I have mimicked this functionality with Oh My Zsh, as follows (in the theme file):

```
WATSON_DIR="$HOME/Library/Application Support/watson"
watson_status() {
    local txtred="${fg_bold[red]}"
    local txtgrn="${fg_bold[green]}"
    local txtrst="${reset_color}"

    # Started
    local status_color="$txtgrn"

    # Stopped
    if [[ $(cat "$WATSON_DIR/state") == '{}' ]]; then
        status_color="$txtred"
    fi
    echo -e "$status_color""◉""$txtrst"
}

PROMPT="╭── %{$(watson_status) $fg_bold[green]%}%~%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info) ⌚ %{$FG[130]%}%*%{$reset_color%}
╰─➤ $ "
```

## Current issue

The icon will indicate the color of the state at the time that .zshrc was executed. For example, if the timer is running and the icon is properly indicating green, stopping the timer will not cause the icon to turn red. In order to see the icon change color, I have to source .zshrc.

This indicates that the function `watson_status()` needs to be run each time a command is executed, to give the latest status at the time of the command

Comment: That might not be the answer you want to hear, but zsh (and any other shell) are not meant to be used this way (otherwise, shell command could be slowed or maliciously changed for other other purposes). If you want to check the status of 'something', the only sound way to do that is 1/ use a cron job 2/if you want to be notified immediately of a problem while running a shell window, use 'wall' broadcast, in conjunction with an email or sms text.

Comment: Before I moved to zsh (when I used bash), I was able to do this without issue using PS1. All I did was use the exact same function above `watson_status()`, but then export the PS1. Of course, the functionality is different when using `oh my zsh`, but I don't see why it couldn't be done the way I used to have it

Comment: I didn't mean it's impossible, I'm just saying that's probably not the right way. If an extra command is executed for each shell command made by a user, what prevents  from inserting malicious code?

Comment: check this, probably what you are looking for : https://superuser.com/questions/735660/whats-the-zsh-equivalent-of-bashs-prompt-command

Comment: `watson_status` is called when `PROMPT` is defined, not displayed. Use single quotes (with some necessary adjustments), just as you would have in `bash`. Also, read up on the `precmd` hook in `man zshmisc` to define your prompt on demand (like `PROMPT_COMMAND` in `bash`) , which is what the question linked by Alex refers to.

Comment: @chepner you are absolutely correct, I had assumed that single and double quotes were interchangeable. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14):

I recently ported some prompt code from bash to zsh - on OSX Big Sur - and these were the two big "things to know" for me:

- add `setopt PROMPT_SUBST` to your .zshrc. This "allows for functions in the prompt"
- use single quotes when defining your PS1 / PROMPT. If you use double quotes, then the whole string will be evaluated once when the terminal starts, and then that evaluated value is "re-executed" every time the command changes. But you want the functions to be re-evaluated, not the output of the function at the time when the terminal is created.

Easiest example I used to confirm I had it working:

```
# print_epoch() { date '+%s' }

# this is what you want
# export PS1='$(print_epoch) > '

# this is not what you want
# export PS1="$(print_epoch) > "
```

Also worth noting PS1 and PROMPT are interchangeable

**Extra:**

While we are sharing here is my fairly minimal echo my user, directory, and git branch PROMPT with some colors and a pretty leaf:

```
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
}

setopt PROMPT_SUBST
autoload -U colors && colors
export PROMPT='%n %~ %F{blue}$(parse_git_branch)%f > '
```

noting that:

- **%n** prints name
- **%~** prints directory relative to home
- **%F{blue}** changes text to blue
- **%f** resets color

Documentation: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects

Comment: "I dont know what the difference between PROMPT and PS1 is ?" There is no difference. `PROMPT` is an alias for `PS1`. Whatever value you set for one will be reflected in the other.

Comment: Instead of `%{$fg[blue]%}`, you can just use `%F{blue}`. And `%b` resets all highlighting. No need to define your own `$reset_color` variable.

Comment: @MarlonRichert I have incorporated your feedback. I couldn't get %b to work, but %F works as color reset

Comment: Sorry, it seems that `%b` resets all highlighting, _except_ color. My bad. The correct way to reset color is to use `%f`. I submitted an edit to your answer.